# MonoGame: Some VertexColorPosition dissappear while drawing user primitives(DrawUserPrimitives)

Tags: xna-4.0, primitive, monogame

I am a complete beginner in XNA/MonoGame developing. I started my own project using MonoGame with XAML for WinRT, hopefully that it will reach Windows App Store one day. I encountered a serious issue, see the [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d0pA7E5FkdE). I used wireframes so the missing vertices can be easily seen. Only the explosions created by user input are flawless. All of them use the same logic.

I am doing this game with ball collision, pretty simple, indeed. In certain conditions these balls explode and they start to expand following some rules. When the explosion is initiated by user input with the same type explosion, the following explosion do not appear well at all. Some of the vertices of the primitives disappear and they appear as some strange shapes but not circles at all. I tried disabling CullMode(setting it to None), DepthBuffer(setting to false), StencilEnable(setting to false). None of this helped. All of these primitives are in the same z-plane(z = 0). Does anyone have any suggestions? Your help is highly appreciated, thank you a lot. Below you can find the code which gives more details into the situation.

During the update I go through all the objects consecutively, do the necessary updates, and in the same order I call for each of them:

```
this.graphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>(PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip, circleVertices, 0, primitiveCount);
```

This is the BasicEffect that I apply:

```
basicEffect.Projection = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter
           (0, graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width,     // left, right
            graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height, 0,    // bottom, top
            0, 1);                                         // near, far plane
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be hard to answer without seeing more code. It appears from the video that there must be an issue when you are generating the circleVertices for an explosion that starts from user input. Would it be possible to post your code somewhere?

Comment: Thanks you for spending time on this. Here is the link to the drawing logic:

http://pastebin.com/BRVuTXrf

Comment: Is this the same question from the GameDev stack? http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/47683/disappearring-instances-of-vertexpositioncolor-using-monogame ?

Comment: Exactly the same instance. :) Thanks for the advice, but it did not help.

Comment: If you want to send me the code for the entire project, I can try to debug it for you.